# "Disk Not Ejected Properly" after MBP went to sleep

Tags: hard-drive, sleep-wake, external-disk, eject

I have an external HDD connected to my MBP (2016 model). Everytime the machine goes to sleep I get the "Disk Not Ejected Properly" message, which I find annoying. There doesn't seem to be a real problem. The drive is reconnected and accessible so it seems to be just annoying.

The questions are:

1. Is this really just something annoying, or is there an actual problem with this?
2. How can I make the notifications go away?

The HDD is a "LaCie Porsche Design Mobile Drive - 1 TB"

I have seen this question: [External hard disc not ejected properly - Mac OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83953/external-hard-disc-not-ejected-properly-mac-osx) but it is rather old, blames the behavior on a special brand of hdd and also is about the drive not being usable, so I think my question is different.

Comment: Not much of an answer hence the comment: The problem did go away. I don't know why.